# Using the CASE conditon in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
ID  Desc    IsWatchList
1   Desc1   1
2   Desc2   0
3   Desc3   0
4   Desc4   1
5   Desc5   1
6   Desc6   0
```

I have one Variable @WatchList

If @WatchList = 'yes' then i would like to select below records

```
ID  Desc    IsWatchList
1   Desc1   1
4   Desc4   1
5   Desc5   1
```

If @WatchList = 'no'then i would like to select all records below

```
ID  Desc    IsWatchList
1   Desc1   1
2   Desc2   0
3   Desc3   0
4   Desc4   1
5   Desc5   1
6   Desc6   0
```

How would I use the CASE condition in Where Clause?

Comment: Why did you tag the question with MySQL and Oracle tags, if it is related to MS SQL server?

Comment: What type is `@WatchList`

Answer (score 2):

If `@WatchList` has only two states, 0 and 1 (or 'yes' and 'no'), then you won't even need to resort to a `CASE WHEN` in the `WHERE` clause. You can do:

```
SELECT Id, Desc, IsWatchList
FROM MyTable
WHERE IsWatchList = 1 OR @WatchList = 0;
```

(If it is two states, I would also recommend changing the type of `@WatchList` to `BIT` to constrain the state)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use OR condition. it will do your job.

```
Select * from MyTable
WHERE (@WatchList = 'NO' OR (@WatchList = 'yes' AND IsWatchList =1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @table table(id int, [desc] varchar(100), iswatchlist bit);
    insert into @table values (1,'desc1',1)
    insert into @table values (2,'desc2',0)
    insert into @table values (3,'desc3',0)
    insert into @table values (4,'desc4',1)
    insert into @table values (5,'desc5',1)
    insert into @table values (6,'desc6',1)
    declare @bit varchar(3) = 'yes'
    select id,[desc],isWatchList from @table where isWatchList >= case @bit when 'no' then 0 when 'yes' then 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use `>=`

```
declare @WatchList bit = 0

select *
from table1
where IsWatchList >= @WatchList
;

| ID |  Desc | IsWatchList |
|----|-------|-------------|
|  1 | Desc1 |        true |
|  2 | Desc2 |       false |
|  3 | Desc3 |       false |
|  4 | Desc4 |        true |
|  5 | Desc5 |        true |
|  6 | Desc6 |       false |


declare @WatchList bit = 1

select *
from table1
where IsWatchList >= @WatchList
;

| ID |  Desc | IsWatchList |
|----|-------|-------------|
|  1 | Desc1 |        true |
|  4 | Desc4 |        true |
|  5 | Desc5 |        true |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2a59f/1